# Axios Get request - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm creating a User search, always when I write on input needs to return all user that I search, but on back-end is returning **undefined**...

Front code where I make Requests:

```js
    import api from "../apis/api"; // axios configuration

    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

    function SearchUser() {
      const [ user, setUser ] = useState({userName: "",});
      const [ found, setFound ] = useState([]);
      console.log("found Search -> ", found) // []


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setUser({ ...user, [event.currentTarget.name]: event.currentTarget.value })
    }


      useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUser() {
          try {
            console.log("user-> ", user) // user->  {userName: "user"}
            const response = await api.get("/search", {userName: user.userName});

            setFound({ ...response.data });
            
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.response);
          }
        }
        fetchUser();
      }, [user.userName]);
```

Back-End code, where **userName returns undefined** after Front-end request:

```js
router.get("/search", isAuthenticated, attachCurrentUser, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { userName } = req.body;

    console.log("userName -> ", userName); // userName ->  undefined

  const response = await UserModel.find({
    profileName: {
      $regex: userName.toLowerCase(),
      $options: "i",
    },
  });
  return res.status(200).json(response);

    
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(404).json({ msg: "User not found" });
  }
});
```

I really don't understand why userName is undefined on Back-End code...

Comment: Did you try to print the ```req.body```, also did you use the middleware ```body-parser``` ?

Comment: There is no body when you use get. You can pass the param as a query string or change your method to post and handle the value in body.

Comment: Hey, this is req.body print // req.body ->  {}
I'm using useNewUrlParser: true, from mongoose

Comment: I changed to Post has you told Sanish, now is working !! Thanx